# Cannot login to a website using HtmlUnit 2.35.0

Tags: java, authentication, htmlunit

I want to login to https://www.rjs.com/member/user.html#login using `HtmlUnit` but failed, I still get the previous page after calling login button.click.

It will be great appreciated if anyone can help me on this issue.

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
webClient.setCssErrorHandler(new SilentCssErrorHandler()); 
webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
webClient.getOptions().setTimeout(50000);
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
webClient.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true); 
webClient.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true); 
HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://www.rjs.com/member/user.html#login");
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10000);
System.out.println(page.asXml());
HtmlInput heUsername = (HtmlInput)page.getHtmlElementById("login_username");
HtmlPasswordInput hePassword = (HtmlPasswordInput)page.getHtmlElementById("login_pwd");
HtmlButton heLogin = (HtmlButton)(page.getFirstByXPath("//button[@class='login-btn']"));
heUsername.setValueAttribute(<my user name>);
hePassword.setValueAttribute(<my password>);
HtmlPage page2 = heLogin.click();
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10000);
System.out.println(page2.asXml());
webClient.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without having credentials, i can't validate your problem. Only some general hints

1. keep the WebClient setup as simple as possible, the defaults are usually good. From my point of view you need only

   ```
   webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
   webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
   ```
2. use type() for filling entry fields

   ```
   heUsername.type(<my user name>);
   hePassword.type(<my password>);
   ```
3. if you wait for the js to finish after the login it is usually a good idea to reget the page from the window because the js might have loaded a different page after the login.

   ```
   HtmlPage page2 = heLogin.click();
   webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10000);
   page2 = ((HtmlPage) page2.getEnclosingWindow().getEnclosedPage());
   ```

Hope that helps. And as always maybe the logs are also containing useful hints.

Comment: Hi RBRi, thank you very much, I tried your suggestions but still got the same results, you can use my test credentials (username:18601246140, password:passw0rd) to validate my issue, thanks again.

Comment: Ok, will try. Can you please open a github issue for HtmlUnit. This will make it simpler for me to track the issues.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to open a github issue for HtmlUnit.

Comment: https://help.github.com/en/articles/creating-an-issue; HtmlUnit is at https://github.com/HtmlUnit/htmlunit

Comment: Thank you so much, your solution posted in the issue worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work here (using the latest 2.36.0-SNAPSHOT) build.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String uri = "https://www.rjs.com/member/user.html#login";

    try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_60)) {
        HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(uri);
        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10000);

        HtmlInput heUsername = (HtmlInput) page.getHtmlElementById("login_username");
        HtmlPasswordInput hePassword = (HtmlPasswordInput) page.getHtmlElementById("login_pwd");
        HtmlButton heLogin = (HtmlButton) page.getFirstByXPath("//button[@class='login-btn']");
        heUsername.type(....);
        hePassword.type(....);

        heLogin.click();
        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10000);

        page = (HtmlPage) webClient.getCurrentWindow().getEnclosedPage();
        System.out.println("----------------");
        System.out.println(page.asXml());
    }
}
```